# Any Code Based Driver Optimizations for Far-Object Rendering?

Tags: optimization, level-of-detail, nvidia, filtering

***Are there any video card driver optimizations available to developers*** to mitigate considerable framerate drops (%50+) which may be caused by Draw Distance defects in a game?

For example, when using a dependency injection pattern - to inject DirectX or Vulkan dependencies into the game library after the fact. (A game engine that may be reused, inefficient, and locked.)

Which cross-API driver features are there - to optimize framerate issues due to rendering distant objects.  (LoD, etc.)

**Example :**

In a game zone, when the camera is redirected - there is a significant / sharp drop in framerate (50%+), due to the number / complexity of objects far away.

A good example of this is in Dark Souls 3, the Ringed City, Dredge Heap Bonfire.

Comment: If the game engine's code base is locked, then this doesn't sound like a game development problem so much as a game playing problem, and might be more on-topic at [Arqade](http://www.gaming.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be a question related to end-user configuration, and not about developing a game.

Comment: **A.)** I updated the question - to clarify that that the game engine code base is decoupled from the graphics interfaces - specifically, graphics configuration.  **B.)** And yes, I agree that the part about end-users configuring specific graphics options is very borderline, on/off topic.  **C.)** Regardless, I feel that the specific video card configuration options available to developers is on-topic.

Comment: Could you expand on this? _"Assuming that the code-base is decoupled - where the actual game-engine code is locked, but the graphics interface implementations are not."_ I'm not sure I get what the distinction is between 'game-engine' and 'graphics interface' in the context of the question.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt - I tried clarifying the question - rephrasing it in terms of the dependency injection pattern.

Comment: @JustinWilliamStanleyBryant - **A.)** I understand that the driver is unaware of draw distance, and that makes sense; **B.)** But, are there driver options regarding LoD, supersampling, mipmapping, etc ... that may reduce the GPU load of rendering those objects that are far away?  **C.)** If not, then I think clarifying that would be the answer to the question.

Comment: @JustinWilliamStanleyBryant - **A.)** Thank you.  It sounds very much like your last two comments are actually acceptable as an answer : "No, there is nothing that can be done at that point" - with those explanations.  **B.)** Could you post as an answer, please?

Comment: Done and done, ill remove my comments to keep it clean down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing that can be done at that point.

A GPU driver has no idea about Draw Distance, that is controlled by the farclip of the camera.

Its up to the developer to implement many of the optimizations you just mentioned, while mipmapping is built into the GPU that's sort of something that every game will use but it hasn't really got anything to do with far away objects. When an IHV makes driver optimizations its normally to do with the way the API is used and any funky shaders\usage patterns.